# Adding Noise Texture Node to Material Using Python

Tags: python, procedural

I am trying to create a Noise Texture Node on a material, but nothing is working from the examples I have found.
I have an existing material and just need to add the node to my material graph.

I have seen conflicting names for how this node is called online. I can make other shader nodes

```
import bpy
import math
import random
import mathutils



objects = bpy.data.objects
cube = objects.get("Cube")
matBody = cube.material_slots["body"].material



# Enable 'Use nodes' for destined Materials
matBody.use_nodes = True

noise_1 = matBody.node_tree.nodes.new("Noise Texture")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok The issue was with the name, after finding this great collection of how to Python scripts in Blender by SpectralVectors

https://github.com/SpectralVectors/BlenderPythonShorts#how-to-get-the-vscode-extension-working-in-blender-3-and-up

Basically the name of the Noise Texture Shader node must be "ShaderNodeTexNoise" and the parameters are described below the code.

```
# Create and Edit a Shader Node Tree

import bpy

# Create a Material to hold the Node Tree
material = bpy.data.materials.new(name='MyCoolMaterial')
material.use_nodes = True
material.node_tree.nodes.clear()

# Create the Node Tree
nodes = material.node_tree.nodes

# Add a Material Output, then any other nodes you want
output = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeOutputMaterial')

# Add a Principled BSDF Shader, and adjust some values
bsdf = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled')
# Set the Base Color to Green
bsdf.inputs[0].default_value = (0, 1, 0, 1)
# Set the Roughness to 1
bsdf.inputs[9].default_value = 1
# Move the node 100 pixels to the left, so it does not overlap the 
Material Output node
bsdf.location[0] += -100

# Add a Noise Texture Node
noise = nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeTexNoise')
# Increase the Scale to 7
noise.inputs[2].default_value = 7
# Move it 200 pixels to the left so it does not overlap the Output or BSDF 
nodes
noise.location[0] += -200

# Now to connect the nodes
links = material.node_tree.links
# Create a connection between the first output of the Principled BSDF and 
the first input of the Material Output
links.new(bsdf.outputs[0], output.inputs[0])
# Create a connection between the first output of the Noise node and the 
Metallic input of the Principled BSDF
links.new(noise.outputs[0], bsdf.inputs[6])

# Now we add the material to the active object, otherwise it will be 
created but not used
bpy.context.object.data.materials.append(material)

The Shader Must be defined and node Trees must be available for the tree
```